# how to install SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

this one seems trivial, but when I try to follow the Link at Step 3 here:

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild

(Download the latest version of the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild), I land on the same page.

Where do I find this? (I've checked various bits of sonarqube software I have installed, but don't find it tucked away in any of these.)

Answer (score 0):

The download link is at the top of that page.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks! My suspicion that I was missing something obvious is confirmed. Merci!

Comment: By the way, maybe it would make sense:

- in Step 3 "Download the latest version of the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild (using the link at the top of the page)" to unlink "SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild" since it is a self-link (and confused at least me. :))

- on the first line of Step 6 "Edit C:\SonarQube\bin\SonarQube.Analysis.xml to specify the following parameters:" you might correct the path (in the version I just unpacked SonarQube.Analysis.xml is two directories above the bin directory I find).

Comment: That _would_ make sense @Tim but that particular piece of text is an include used in 2 places. For now I added the parenthetical. Long term... we have to weigh the risk of those two instances getting out of sync if we drop the include mechanism.